# Which library to replace requests module post in AWS lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, python-requests, urllib, python-module, urllib3

Since python 3.6 version lambda functions won't be supported by AWS in future, I'm looking to replace requests module which uses requests.post(url,data,headers,json) by any other python modules which does similar functionality in python 3.9+ versions. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an alternative to `requests`, you can use e.g. https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/. However, if you want to keep using `requests`, you can still use it in newer Python versions (like 3.9) without issues. Did you find that to not be the case?

Comment: In AWS, the lambda runtimes for python 3.8 and later do not include 'requests' module. I have a lambda function of python 3.6 that uses 'requests' module. so i'm looking for an alternative for 'requests' to be used,compatible with AWS SDK

Comment: I see, `requests` is just an external library that you can continue to use with Python3.8 runtime, but you need to include it in your deployment package. If you want to stick to things available out of the box, you might want to check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request from standard library. But honestly, I would recommend you to keep using `requests`, but just include it in your package.

Comment: Yes, I have been considering to use deployment package. Thanks @pgrzesik